# How do I find Status=act value after Status=low value?

Tags: mysql

I have one table which have records like below

tableA

```
subid clickid status datetime
1     123     low    2018-07-24 20:20:44
2     123     act    2018-07-24 21:20:44
3     231     act    2018-07-25 20:20:44
4     231     low    2018-07-25 21:20:44
5     789     low    2018-07-26 20:20:44
6     789     act    2018-07-26 21:20:44
```

Example of my table is above.

Now I need find those records/users who has status = 'low' and then status = 'act'.

I mean clickid 123 & 789 are what I need as my output.

First **status** value should be **low** then **act**. Because some records also be there like status = act first then status = low. Ex clickid=231. But I want status= low then status = act. Ex clickid=123&789.

NOTE : **clickid** is a user identification

What kind of Query I can use for this?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    status= 'low') a
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    status= 'act') b ON a.clickid = b.clickid where a.datetime < b.datetime;
```

Answer (score 2):

If always have *at most* two records per `clickid` then you can use:

```
SELECT clickid
FROM TableA
GROUP BY clickid
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'low' THEN datetime END) <
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'act' THEN datetime END)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4171d/1)

To ensure that one record is a 'low' and the other one is an 'act' you can add the following predicates to `HAVING`:

- `SUM(status = 'low') = 1`
- `SUM(status = 'act') = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try it doing a join:

```
SELECT t1.clickid 
  FROM tableA AS t1
  JOIN tableA AS t2 
    ON t1.clickid = t2.clickid 
   AND t1.status = 'act'
   AND t2.status = 'low' 
   AND t2.datetime < t1.datetime
GROUP BY t1.clickid
```

Here is a demo too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f861/1/0

Answer (score 1):

you could use a self join

```
 select a.clickid, a.status, b.clickid, b.status 
 from tableA a 
 inner join tableA b on a.clickid = b.clickid 
      and a.datetime < b.datetime 
          and a.status = 'low' 
              and b.status ='act'
```